# ByteArray to IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload

I am developing some REST API with C# and Net Core
I have a function in my repository which accepts a parameter of type `IFormFile`.

```
public async Task<bool> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    // do some stuff and save the file to azure storage
}
```

This function is called by a controller method which pass it the uploaded file

```
public class FileController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDoc(IFormFile file
    {
        // Call the repository function to save the file on azure
        var res = await documentRepository.UploadFile(file);
    }
}
```

Now I have another function that calls an external API which returns a file as a byte array. I'd like to save this byte array using the `repository.UploadFile` method but I can't cast the byte array object to `IFormFile`.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your repo shouldn't be using `IFormFile`. That's an abstraction that only applies to *one* particular method of HTTP file transfer (namely a `multipart/form-data` encoded request body). Something like your repo should have no knowledge of the source of the file (HTTP), nor *how* it was transmitted (`multipart/form-data` vs `application/json` for example).

Instead, you should use `Stream` for your param. In your `UploadDoc` action, then, you can simply do:

```
using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
{
    await documentRepository.UploadFile(stream);
}
```

And, where you have just a byte array:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    await documentRepository.UploadFile(stream);
}
```

You might also consider adding an overload of `UploadFile` that takes a `byte[]`, as creating a new memory stream from a byte array just to have a stream is a waste of resources. However, a `byte[]` has to be handled differently than a `Stream`, so it may require some duplication of logic to go that route. You'll need to evaluate the tradeoffs.

Answer (score 36):

You can convert the byte array to a `MemoryStream`:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

..and then pass that to the constructor of the [`FromFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formfile) class:

```
IFormFile file = new FormFile(stream, 0, byteArray.Length, "name", "fileName");
```

Comment: It error like after I tried your code, please kindly give some advise.

'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

thanks you.

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a new MemoryStream based on the byte array.
2. Create a new FormFile object based on the MemoryStream.
3. Make sure to append the ContentDisposition header, otherwise you will be unable to operate your FormFile object as a C# exception will be thrown.

The complete code:

```
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            var file = new FormFile(stream, 0, byteArray.Length, name, fileName)
            {
                Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
                ContentType = contentType,
            };

            System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = file.FileName
            };
            file.ContentDisposition = cd.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Does this only work in the controllers? I'm trying to do this in a class library, and no matter what NuGet package I install, FormFile is not part of the assembly.  I've tried Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile, and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile.  I'm currently still on .Net Core 3.1.