# How do I process ClosedXML excel workbook into IFormFile? C#

Tags: c#, excel, type-conversion, closedxml

How do I convert a ClosedXML excel workbook into an IFormFile?

```
XLWorkbook myWorkbook = //Workbook
IFormFile myFile = myWorkbook
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get byte array from workbook using method `ToByteArray` defined in `XLWorkbook` type and then use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/58378590/10304482.

Hope this helps